# What is the maximum results returned for YouTube Data API v3 call

Tags: api, youtube, limit

## Context

I am in the process of providing some consultancy on doing a HTTP GET using YouTube Data API V3; in order to develop a Windows based application to GET a list of results from Youtube, for say a specific CATEGORY, or a specific TAG.

We are open to using any programming language(I'm from a C++ background and am hoping You tube will support direct HTTP connections without using Google client SDK and so on) to connect to YouTube and (HTTP) GET data.(Once a month or so, so YouTube API  quotas should not be problem).

## The Issue

We are being told by some of my client's web developers that YouTube API v3 will only return a maximum of 500 records/results, for say a query that returns JUST the Total viewers, the Video's link, and basic meta data such as that.

S, say I wish to find 5,000 results for category "House music" or "basketball" - and I have the Developer Key etc are all set up, would that be possible?

If so, what GET  fields would I need to populate(such as "max_results_per_page")?

Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The API won't provide more than **~500** search results for any arbitrary query. It's by design. Technically, it means that the `nextPageToken` field won't be returned once you hit ~500 results. No additional parameter can change that.

If you want more than ~500 results for a query, you have to split it into more specific sub-queries. I'd suggest using the `publishedAfter` and `publishedBefore` parameters to achieve that, but feel free to experiment with the other ones [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list).

Comment: Interesting.. thank you for that. I am in learning mode here, as YouTube API is not my forte.

Comment: Just another update : I have tried out the publishedAfter/Before fields and find that YouTube API v3 doesn't even accept it.. They're very strict with V3 of the API. Will keep searching for new solutions..

Comment: @BuddhaMaitreya That's a shame, good luck, please post the solution here if you find it

Comment: @BuddhaLight Make sure you are using an rfc339 formatted timestamp.

Comment: Thank you. This project never went ahead, but it's good to know  useful info. Thanks again.

Comment: Anybody happen to know where this ~500 limit is in the YouTube docs?

Comment: So, it's paginated (max of 50 results per page) and limited to a max of about 10 pages before just bailing on the user? How do they use their own API to list beyond 10 pages worth then?

Answer (score 0):

This only holds for the search-Query. Other queries like "PlaylisItem:list" deliver more results. I have tested with 100.000 items to get the videos of a playlist.

Comment: Can you please add a bit more details about this?

Comment: What if a video is not added to a playlist?