# Why do I get inconsistent results consuming the v3 YouTube API?

Tags: youtube, youtube-data-api

As far as I can tell, I'm paging through API results as I should:

- Make a request
- Get a result back containing the 'totalResults' and the 'nextPage' token
- Make the same request, adding the 'pageToken' parameter

Some issues I'm having:

- If I make any request multiple times, I'll often get one of two different 'totalResults' values
- If I page through and grab all the results for various queries, I'll get different numbers of items

Here's a set of queries followed by their 'nextPage' and 'totalResults' values:

> https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=~key~&part=id&channelId=UC8hzWaP0JfFJ8a1UjLIl1FA&maxResults=50&publishedAfter=2016-02-23T14%3A32%3A58.928-06%3A00&publishedBefore=2017-02-24T14%3A32%3A58.928-06%3A00&type=video

CDIQAA/239

> https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=~key~&part=id&channelId=UC8hzWaP0JfFJ8a1UjLIl1FA&maxResults=50&**pageToken=CDIQAA**&publishedAfter=2016-02-23T14%3A32%3A58.928-06%3A00&publishedBefore=2017-02-24T14%3A32%3A58.928-06%3A00&type=video

CGQQAA/188

> https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=~key~&part=id&channelId=UC8hzWaP0JfFJ8a1UjLIl1FA&maxResults=50&**pageToken=CGQQAA**&publishedAfter=2016-02-23T14%3A32%3A58.928-06%3A00&publishedBefore=2017-02-24T14%3A32%3A58.928-06%3A00&type=video

CJYBEAA/188

> https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=~key~&part=id&channelId=UC8hzWaP0JfFJ8a1UjLIl1FA&maxResults=50&**pageToken=CJYBEAA**&publishedAfter=2016-02-23T14%3A32%3A58.928-06%3A00&publishedBefore=2017-02-24T14%3A32%3A58.928-06%3A00&type=video

null/239

The first three queries contained 50 items, and the last contained 18, so I got 168 items total.  This is really frustrating since I don't know if any of the three counts is the correct count.

Again, if I put any one query in my browser and hit 'refresh' over and over, I'll get either 188 or 239.

Comment: You're not alone.. My experience was that `totalResults` stabilises to one number after a few calls with the `pageToken` as latest `nextPageToken`. There's numerous inconsistencies, just does not do what it says on the box. Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23255957/what-is-the-maximum-results-returned-for-youtube-data-api-v3-call) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31759677/cannot-page-through-all-results-using-nextpagetoken-on-youtube-search-api-v3?rq=1) for extra ideas.