# Youtube Selenium scraper (scraping usernames with less then 500 creators) Python, no visible error

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, youtube

I have the code that is supposed to open video links on youtube by the keyword that user picks and my code is opening the links, but however it stops at certain moment and there is no visible error, it simply stops going through videos and it doesn't show up the users with less than 500 subscribers, if you can see the mistake that I'm making, please let me know. Here is the code I have written so far:

```
# Import necessary modules
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

# Ask the user to enter a keyword to search for
keyword = input("Enter a keyword to search for: ")

# Create a new instance of the Chrome driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

# Navigate to the YouTube homepage
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com")

# Find the search box and enter the keyword
search_box = driver.find_element_by_name("search_query")
search_box.send_keys(keyword)
search_box.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

# Wait for the search results to load
time.sleep(2)

# Find all video links on the search results page
video_links = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a#video-title")

# Create a list to store the usernames of creators with less than 500 subscribers
less_than_500_subs = []

# Loop through each video link and check the number of subscribers for the creator
for link in video_links:
    link.click()
    time.sleep(2)
    try:
        subscribers = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("yt-formatted-string#owner-sub-count").text.replace("subscribers", "").strip()
        if "K" in subscribers:
            subscribers = float(subscribers.replace("K", "")) * 1000
        elif "M" in subscribers:
            subscribers = float(subscribers.replace("M", "")) * 1000000
        else:
            subscribers = float(subscribers)
        if subscribers < 500:
            username = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a#channel-name").get_attribute("title")
            if username not in less_than_500_subs:
                less_than_500_subs.append(username)
    except (NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException):
        pass
    driver.back()
    time.sleep(2)

# Print the list of usernames with less than 500 subscribers
print("Usernames with less than 500 subscribers:")
for username in less_than_500_subs:
    print(username)

# Close the browser window
driver.quit()
```

No visible error!

Comment: How many results do you retrieve before *it stops*? If about 500, then you're facing [this known issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23256768).

Comment: Around 20 videos, I dont exactly understand why. Do you have any idea what can it be?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be the issue but please upgrade to the latest version of Selenium otherwise up to date reviewers are facing errors like `AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_name'`.